# Call function defined in body from head

Tags: javascript, function

I have this simple HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script>
       share();
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
          function share() {
                alert('test');
          }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

I need to call the function share from the `<head>` and the function itself must be defined in the `<body>`.

The above code leads to undefined function error.

This is just a simplified script to explain the issue so it needs to be done that way. Is there a way around this?

Comment: you could wait till the dom is ready.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: It simply won't work since the function share hasn't been initialized yet.  You can only call functions in javascript after it is declared.  Javascript can't compile it self so that is why.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the body to be loaded, so

```
<html>
<head>
   <script>
   window.onload=share;
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <script>
      function share() {
            alert('test');
      }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
     <html>
        <head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
           <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               share();
            });
           </script>

        </head>
        <body>
           <script>
              function share() {
                    alert('test');
              }
           </script>
```

Comment: Assuming you have jquery loaded which you don't have in that sample

Comment: Sorry about that. Added it

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
    <html>
    <head>
       <script>
        windows.onload = function(){
           share();
        }
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <script>
          function share() {
                alert('test');
          }
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

or you can use `Jquery` version

```
  <html>
        <head>
         <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
           <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
               share();
            });
           </script>
        </head>
        <body>
           <script>
              function share() {
                    alert('test');
              }
           </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Both of them work in this condition however if you want to know the difference between this tow I suggest to see this
[window.onload vs $(document).ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)